# How to obtain tables columns in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out if the database exists, and if it does exist obtain the columns of a table and the data inside. Right now it is only returning the name of the table itself..I should also mention that I am using MS SQL Server

so far I know that I can do something like this:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases WHERE Name = 'Biometric')

SELECT * FROM Biometric.sys.tables WHERE Name = 'PERSON' 

ELSE

SELECT 'FALSE' as Fingerprint
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyTest.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`

Answer (score 0):

```
IF DB_ID('Biometric') IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
     SELECT  t.name , c.name
     FROM Biometric.sys.tables t 
     INNER JOIN Biometric.sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
     WHERE t.Name = 'PERSON' 
   END
ELSE 
   BEGIN
     SELECT 'FALSE' as Fingerprint
   END
```

Comment: Oh shoot, I failed to mention that I need to obtain not just the columns but I need to see what data is inside of the table itself. sorry, but that is correct for what I asked thanks M.